# Aggregate Functions And GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I have following query as homework for sql:-

> Write a query that tells how many books each author has written. On
>   each row provide first the authorid, followed by the number of books.
>   Order the listing so that the author with the most books written is at
>   the top, and at the bottom are those that have written the fewest
>   number of books. The authors that the same number of books written are
>   further ordered by their AuthorID's in an increasing order.

I have already tried different options via replacing groupby, orderby and count() functions.

```
SELECT authorid as "authorid",
        COUNT (bookid) as "count"
FROM book
GROUP by authorid
HAVING COUNT (bookid) >=1
ORDER BY   COUNT (bookid) DESC;
```

Your result

```
authorid    count
204 4
202 3
206 1
201 1
207 1
205 1
```

Expected result

```
authorid    count
204 4
202 3
201 1
205 1
206 1
207 1
```

Comment: Your result is a **possible** result as the records where `count=1` are non deterministic because the values "tie", because off that you can get different results on multiple runs..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing this condition:

> The authors that the same number of books written are further ordered by their AuthorID's in an increasing order.

That requires a second `ORDER BY` key:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(bookid) DESC, authorid;
```

Comment: @Victor . . . Good luck with your studies.